# Multiseat on ubuntu 14.04 on video card Intel HD (VGA+DVI-D)

Tags: 14.04, multiseat

I Have idea make the Multiseat system for home.

My Configuration:

1. Basicaly integraded graphics card Intel with two ports VGA & DVI-D.
2. Processor Intel Pentium G3420 with integraded graphics.
3. OS Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.
4. Two LCD monitors.
5. Two complects mouses and keyboards.

I read instructions on: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions
- but this variant is for two cards and I have only one video card. I think - Xephyr - uses the right method, but i don`t know how to. Now i have xorg.conf file, but he is a wrong configured... http://pastebin.com/CE7Eqduh

Please Help! I don`t know what the do?!